# GAS webapp table refreshes after second click

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Hy everyone!
I built an handy html table. Here you have the url workable example: [LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DIVs4gmI4ea2pRR0zI6xE1ndxMIqjnNXNrxRpn0ChZg/edit?usp=sharing)
You can make a copy of it and see the full google apps script code both frontend and backend.
The problem here is this: when I open the page and the "change" event reload the table  the data retrieved are from last but one.
I suspect the problem is in this frontend function but I can't figure out where:

```
function generateTable1(dataArray) {
  var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body");
  tbody.innerHTML = "";
  dataArray.forEach(function(r) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var col1 = document.createElement("td");
    col1.textContent = r[0];
    var col2 = document.createElement("td");
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute('href', `${r[1]}`); // replace "link.html" with your own link
    a.target = "_blank";
    a.innerHTML = "CLICK";
    col2.appendChild(a);
    row.appendChild(col1);
    row.appendChild(col2);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });
  console.log("FLAG1");
}
document.getElementById("itemBando").addEventListener("change", function(e) {

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable1).getTableDataDaQuery();
})
```

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance
Mauro

Comment: What's the workflow here? When is the data meant to be updated and from where? How is the sheet populated?

Comment: If your missing one line then perhaps you haven't got the correct number of rows in your getRange().

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved, thanks for the fantastic suggestion from a contributor. This is the code:
Frontend side (index.html):

```
function getTableDataDaQuery() {
  // FUNZIONE CHE RESITUTISCE I DATI DALLA QUERY

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(
    'Query-restituzione'
  );

  const data = [];

  if (sheet.getLastRow() > 1) data.push(...sheet.getDataRange().getValues());

  return data;
}
```

and in backend side (Codice.gs):

```
function dataDropDown1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(
    'Copia di stati'
  );

  var dataStati = sheet
    .getRange(2, 8, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1)
    .getValues()
    .filter((row) => row[0] !== '');

  return dataStati;
}
```